# Inverse tangent proof

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Given the equation :
$$F(X) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi}(\arctan x + \frac{x}{1+x^2}) $$
Given that $x \geq 0$, I need to show the following :
$$ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi}(\arctan x) \leq F(x) \leq \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{\pi}(\arctan x)$$

I know that $0 \leq \frac{x}{1+x^2} \leq \frac{1}{2}$ , so considering the biggest case I have
$$ \frac{1}{\pi}(\arctan x + \frac{x}{1+x^2}) \leq \frac{1}{\pi}(\arctan x + \frac{1}{2})$$

but I am not sure if I am on the right track as I don't know how to proceed.

Any advice on how to continue would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\arctan x -\frac x {1+x^{2}}$. Then $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)=\frac  1{1+x^{2}}-\frac {1-x^{2}} {(1+x^{2})^{2}}=\frac {2x^{2}} {(1+x^{2})^{2}}\geq 0$. Hence, $f(x) \ge 0$ for $x \geq 0$. Now the upper bound you have obtained easily gives the desired upper bound.

Comment: Ah so since $\arctan x \geq \frac{x}{1+x^2}$, and $ \frac{x}{1+x^2} \geq 0$ the inequality holds. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Prove that
$$\arctan{x}\ge\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}$$
or
$$f(x):=(x^2+1)\arctan{x}-x\ge 0.$$

Since
$$f'(x)=2x\arctan{x}\ge 0,x\ge 0,$$
we have that
$$f(x) \ge f(0)=0.$$

Comment: may be better to use something other than $F$ to avoid confusion with OP's $F$